# Декодировать данные полученные от escape()

Tags: javascript, php

Какой функцией в php можно декодировать данные, закодированные в javascript функцией escape()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urldecode

ну так я вам направление дал:

```
function utf8_urldecode($str) {
    $str = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($str));

    return html_entity_decode($str,null,'UTF-8');;
}
```

Comment: Не берет. Вот как стока выглядит:

%u041F%u0440%u043E%u0435%u043A%u0442 %u0434%u043E%u043C%u0430 %u043D%u043E%u043C%u0435%u0440